# can not get rid of an old initrd.img

Tags: 18.04, initrd

I can get rid of initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
here are my trouble shooting steps

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt purge linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 213161 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic

user@server:/etc/kernel/postrm.d$ sudo rm /boot/initrd.img*
user@server:/etc/kernel/postrm.d$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-135-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-130-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: amd64-microcode: unsupported kernel version!
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_t6H6En/lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_t6H6En/lib/modules/3.13.0-100-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

```
mrjake@pandora:/etc/kernel/postrm.d$ ls -o /boot
total 120975
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   217458 Jan  5 12:18 config-4.15.0-130-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   217458 Jan 18 12:20 config-4.15.0-135-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     1024 Feb  2 16:12 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 13017205 Feb  2 16:28 initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 42212519 Feb  2 16:28 initrd.img-4.15.0-130-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 42213324 Feb  2 16:27 initrd.img-4.15.0-135-generic
drwx------ 2 root    12288 Oct 22  2013 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root  4078450 Jan  5 12:18 System.map-4.15.0-130-generic
-rw------- 1 root  4078490 Jan 18 12:20 System.map-4.15.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root  8388256 Jan  6 06:22 vmlinuz-4.15.0-130-generic
-rw------- 1 root  8392352 Jan 18 12:24 vmlinuz-4.15.0-135-generic
```

and initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic comes back and takes 10mb from my boot partition for nothing. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: `ls -al /var/lib/initramfs-tools/` please.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a file `/boot/vmlinu[zx]-3.13.0-100-generic`.  I would expect that file to be deleted in the `apt purge`, but maybe something went wrong.

Checking a 20.04 installation, `update-initramfs` is just a BASH script that calls `linux-version list` to get the list of installed kernel versions.

`linux-version` is just a PERL script that uses the `DebianLinux.pm` module to get the `image_list`.

The `DebianLinux.pm` PERL module looks for files that match `/boot/vmlinuz-` (or `/boot/vmlinux-` on some architectures) and uses their names to generate the `image_list`.

The browseable source online differs a little from what I see on my system, so behavior could be different depending on release and architecture.

**EDIT**

these are the Debian source references.  They don't all exactly match my installed Ubuntu versions, but the Ubuntu source links don't seem right

https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/-/blob/master/update-initramfs#L187

https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux-base/-/blob/master/bin/linux-version#L84

https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux-base/-/blob/master/lib/DebianLinux.pm#L87

**EDIT 2**

Also check your `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/` directory for `3.13.0-100-generic`.  In `18.04` the `update-initramfs` shell script uses that directory for the list of versions (where `20.04` uses `linux-version`).